# Spring @Autowired annotation is not working in neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j

Repository:

```
@Repository 
public interface NodeRepo extends Neo4jRepository<BaseNode, Long> {
 
     @Query("MATCH (n) WHERE n.nodeId=$nodeId RETURN n")
     BaseNode findByNodeId(String nodeId); 
}
```

Service:

```
@Component 
public class NodeQueryService {

     @Autowired
     NodeRepo nodeRepo;
 
     @Transactional
     public BaseNode fetchPNodeById(String id){
         return nodeRepo.findByNodeId(id);
     } 
}
```

I am using this service in a class where i used

```
@Autowired
NodeQueryService nodeQueryService;
```

But it is giving me this error
services.NodeQueryService.fetchPNodeById(String)" because "this.nodeQueryService" is null

What should i do to make it work ?

Comment: Can you please add the import statements as well to the original post. I guess your @Repository annotation is not the spring stereotype annotation and it can be imported from a different library. It is just a possibility and I cannot surely say unless I see the import statements. So please double check it. thanks!

Comment: First the `@Repository` annotation is useless on a Spring Data repository it doesn't add anything. Second the fact you get a nullpointer isb ecause the class using the `NodeQueryService` isn't spring managed (at least not the instance you are using). Marking as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null. Check also https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/